# Using route group in NextJS 13 stops tailwind from working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

In my NextJS 13 app, Tailwind classes stop being applied when I move page.tsx/layout.tsx from the root of my app directory into a (main) directory (also in the root of my app directory). I imagine there is some config somewhere that is becoming invalidated when I use the route group, but I'm not sure what it is.

This is my tailwind.config file:

```js
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
export default config
```

Comment: Could you please add your `tailwind.config.js` to this question?

Comment: the content config does not seem to have anything from the root, only form the src/ folder

could you show the folder structure before and after? the root with 'src' ??

Comment: My folder hierarchy is src dir containing app dir and within the app dir I have a layout.tsx, page.tsx, globals.css and favicon.ico. The tailwind styling disappears when I move those 4 files from src/app to src/app/(main).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I created a UI component in another folder and forgot to add that to the (content) section in tailwind.config. but if it is not your case check this solution too which was mentioned in tailwind GitHub issues:

```
content: [
'./src/app/(group-name)/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to import the globals.css where you have the directives:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

into all the root layouts of the new route groups. You can just have 1 global css in the root directory

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're referring to a specific requirement in your project or application structure. The instruction suggests that the main page and layout files should be present in the root of the "/app" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be due to the middleware intercepting the requests for your static assets (like CSS files), causing them not to be served correctly. To prevent this, you need to exclude the paths to your static assets from the middleware.

Please add to the below things in your middleware file.

`export const config = { matcher: [ /* * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with: * - api (API routes) * - _next/static (static files) * - _next/image (image optimization files) * - favicon.ico (favicon file) */ '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)', ], }`

Answer (score 0):

Am using expo-router, which uses the same principle of routing in Next js, and I had multiple groups in my app folder, and instead of adding multiple content paths, I added this,

```
  content: [
    "./app/(*)/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
```